# Customizing application.master

Tags: 2007, branding

Whats the best way to customize application.master Master Page without going into the "Microsoft's Unsupported Environment" state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a blog post from a few years ago explaining how to create a httpmodule that sets your normal masterpage to be the one for the application pages.  You can check it out here: http://www.thelineberrys.com/default-category/using-your-sharepoint-sites-master-page-on-all-application-pages-3.html.  This is a supported scenerio.

Comment: Ill second the http module approach. Theres alot of examples of this out there, i think the "original" one was by Steve Caravajal on MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/scaravajal/archive/2007/03/13/sharepoint-branding-and-application-master.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The above reply would be the best approach if you are truly looking to modify the master and need an overhaul.  Otherwise, if you just did a custom theme this would cascade to the application pages.  Unfortunately it usually results in modifying the master.  Looks like you have the option for that. :)

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I've had a great deal of success using a custom style sheet. seems a great deal of the styles are the same across the default and application master pages.

The only difference in one site I branded was the search field that is not included on the application.master.